# Is it possible to animate the border lenght on hover with CSS?

Tags: html, css, hover, border

Here's what I'm trying to achieve: https://streamable.com/hwe5tc

How can this be done?

Is it possible to animate the border-bottom lenght on hover with CSS (From 0% to 100%)?

I've tried inspecting the page but did not find anything that could create this hover animation.

Tried achieving it myself but had no luck. I need some help.

Comment: Typically that's achieved by animating a pseudo-element, or using an SVG as a border image and animating that.

Comment: Hi, i dont know why i can´t answer it properly but yes you can do it. You have to use transition in CSS to be able to get that effect. Heres a link that might help you [link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)